# Change button state by code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

this is xml code that I use to change the button images in my app, according to the state:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/button_n" />

<item android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/button_p" />

</selector>
```

How can I do this by code? I have try this:

```
StateListDrawable sl = new StateListDrawable();

sl.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_pressed}, R.drawable.gridcard_button_p);
```

but addState takes an int array as first argument and a Drawable Object as sedon one (not an int as in my example).

How can I use this method in the right way?

Comment: You don't want the reference R.drawable, you want the path to the actual image. Use `getDrawable(R.drawable..)`

Answer (score 1):

```
 StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
 states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
 getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pressed));
 states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},
 getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.focused));
 states.addState(new int[] { },
 getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal));
 //... like this you can do for remaining
 Button.setImageDrawable(states);
```